# I don't understand my navigation bar (mobile)

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to make a navigation bar for my website but when i go mobile on it my list in my navigation bar moves 40px into the right side of the computer screen where there is nothing.

Can you help me?

Comment: Maybe you didn't know this but we need a link or preferably code, if you want any help.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

In your navigation bar style set the width of the navigation bar to 100% so it will adjust to any size screens.

Add this line to your navigation bar settings "width: 100%;" minus the quotations around it.